# Need to format the super-linter log output

Tags: super-linter

We are running super-linter docker image on Azure DevOps Microsoft hosted agent and linting is happening fine. But we need to format the output of super-linter execution and export these logs outside the agent.

We will try to create a dashboard for the issues that linter is checking.

Is there a way of doing it ?

Nothing specific found as such.